# Change default members tab to popular in elgg

Tags: php, plugins, elgg

I'm writing a plugin in elgg to change default tab of `elgg members` to popular instead of `newest` in members list. But there is a problem. As I set default tab to `popular` then `newest` tab not working anymore.
here is my `start.php` file:

```
<?php
elgg_register_event_handler('init', 'system', 'plug_test_init');

function plug_test_init(){

    elgg_unregister_page_handler('members');
    elgg_register_page_handler('members', 'set_popular_as_default');

}   
function set_popular_as_default($page) {
    if (empty($page[0])) {
        $page[0] = 'popular';
    }
    if ($page[0] == 'search') {
        echo elgg_view_resource('members/search');
    } else {
        echo elgg_view_resource('members/index', [
            'page' => $page[0],
        ]);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [iionly](https://elgg.org/profile/iionly) in [elgg community](https://elgg.org), in [this discussion](https://elgg.org/discussion/view/2536482/need-example-of-hooks-usage) The problem solved by a using hooks of members:

```
<?php
elgg_register_event_handler('init', 'system', 'plug_test_init');

function plug_test_init(){
    elgg_unregister_plugin_hook_handler('members:config', 'tabs', "members_nav_newest");
    elgg_register_plugin_hook_handler('members:config', 'tabs', "my_members_nav_newest");
    elgg_unregister_page_handler('members');
    elgg_register_page_handler('members', 'set_popular_as_default');

}   
function set_popular_as_default($page) {
    if (empty($page[0])) {
        $page[0] = 'popular';
    }
    if ($page[0] == 'search') {
        echo elgg_view_resource('members/search');
    } else {
        echo elgg_view_resource('members/index', [
            'page' => $page[0],
        ]);
    }
    return true;
}
function my_members_nav_newest($hook, $type, $returnvalue, $params) {
        $returnvalue['newest'] = array(
            'title' => elgg_echo('sort:newest'),
            'url' => "members/newest",
        );
     return $returnvalue;
}
```